# Accessing similar structures using variables in loops

Tags: c, structure, field

How can I access multiple structures that are similar using a variable, eg, P1, P2. 
I want to be able to access the subfield turn, eg P1.turn, P2.turn in a loop using a variable for the numeric part. When I compile I get the error "error: request for member `turn' in something not a structure or union". the code is as follows:

```
while (((strcat("P", (char)&pplayer_num))).turn == 0){
```

&pplayer_num starts as an int.

I tried casting the string to a structure but got other errors. 
I know this is probably something simple that I'm just overlooking any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can define a macro, but it would need to be know at compile time, not based on user input.  or consider using a more appropriate data structure like an array of structures

Comment: I was thinking that that array of structures would be the route to go. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically compute the names of variables and then access those variables, C isn't the language you want.  The closest approximation would be to put those variables (or even better, pointers to them) in elements of an array, as those can be dynamically identified by their indices.

Comment: Not enough code presented to know the proper names, but you'll want something like a `struct player P[NPLAYERS];`, after which you can do `P[n].turn == 0`, etc...

Comment: Thats the route I'm coding up now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't work this way.  It looks like you are confusing the way the code looks before it is compiled with how it behaves once it is compiled.  Or rather, you are mixing compile-time with run-time.

That is, you could in theory use something like your code to generate C code (each of the player objects), but you'd need to compile the output to get the behavior you want.  Scripting languages (like python) can lookup values at runtime, but C can't.  It has no idea that you want the string you create (P1) to map to the object/pointer named P1.